# Database for new Android Application

Tags: android, mysql, database, eclipse, sqlite

I'm starting to build a new Android application which will help me to manage material movements in a warehouse. I would like to use use a database for the following applications:

A table that will be managed from a server (my PC probably) to add or delete new users.

Also, there must be another table that will be managed by users. This table will be used to add or delete materials from the warehouse.

I'm not sure what kind of database to use. I have some knowledge of using MySQL Workbench to create and manage databases. However, I've read the SQLite is better for Android applications. Can you please help me to choose which one will be the best for my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the databases run on the android device (which I guess they do not from the description) SQLite is probably the way to go. I like [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) but there are millions out there.

If they run somewhere ales (server) you can choose whatever system you are comfortable with since you will have to implement some protocol to communicate between mobile device and server anyway (most people would use HTTP/REST for that, but again, you can do that in a million ways)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is indeed better for Android applications.

In terms of preloading tables, schemas, and data into a Sqlite database, you can use the SQLiteManager firefox extension to do it.

Or, if you're too lazy to care about what types of database to use, might as well use ORMLite for Android to manage your tables and schemas within your Android application.

As for your server, you'll need to expose the API so that you can do HTTP/RESTful operations on it. You can choose whatever web applications that you prefer.

Comment: Thanks!! I will use HTTP/REST.